# Get information from mySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am trying to use a form and I want when the user submits this form for mySQL to go into my database and get the account id matching the user that is logged in.I don't have a problem with getting the username but i don't know how I would get the account id from mySQL using the username.

So what I am asking is how would I tell mySQL to go and get the account id matching the username that is logged in and then save the account id in a variable.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: @andrewsi I dont have any code I have been working on for this cause I dont know how to do this.All I have is the user varible.

Comment: You should probably start off by reading up on some mysql+php tutorials and get familiar with them.

Comment: Do you at least have the structure of the table you are attempting to query?

Comment: @CrazyWebdesigner123 Yes I want you to use "username" and query it to get a "account_id" in the row with that "username"

Comment: @maxgee So "username" and "accout_id" are the field names.  What is the name of the table?

Answer (score 1):

assuming this is the structure of the table:

```
user:  id|username|otherInfo

select id from user where username='your submitted username';
```

extract from the result set and do whatever

Comment: how would I get the id in a variable?

Comment: I am not using PDO..IK it is becoming unsupported but I am just using the regular connect and query.How would it be done doing those?

Comment: then just use fetch_assoc() instead of fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Answer (score 0):

Detailed description here, assuming this is the structure of the table:

```
user:  account_id|username|otherInfo

//get your posted value(s) and maybe sanitize a bit
$username=htmlentities($_POST['username']);

/* assuming you set up your db connection, using PDO for this example, i'll
 * call that variable $db
 */

//use prepared statement
$pstmt=$db->prepare("select * from user where username=:username");
$pstmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
while($row=$pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id=$row['account_id']; //extracted id        
}
```